# How to convert a date column in TSQL to display only the month and year

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, date

I have a column called `DateId` that is an `int`, and displays the date as `20190626`. I was able to convert it to a date using the below query, but I would like to display it only as Month and Year.

I have three columns `DateId`, `Customer` and `PayAmount`, all from the same table. There are Many customers who have multiple payments each month and I would like to group by each month combining all the payments each month per customer.

```
Select 
    Convert(Date, Convert(Char(8), DateId), 112) As [Date], 
    Sum(PayAmount), Customer 
from 
    Pay 
Group By 
    Customer, DateId
```

What I get:

```
DateId         PayAmount     Customer
--------------------------------------
2019-06-20       $100           A
2019-06-24       $200           B
2019-04-22       $100           B
2019-03-20       $300           A
2019-04-22       $100           B
2019-06-21       $200           A
2019-06-21       $100           B
```

What I want:

```
DateId         PayAmount     Customer
-------------------------------------
2019-06         $300           A
2019-06         $300           B
2019-04         $200           B
2019-03         $300           A
```

Comment: CAST(YEAR(DATEID) as varchar(4)) + '-' + left('0'+CAST(MONTH(DATEID) as varchar(2)),2)

Comment: @PeterSmith Would formatting actually change the underlying value in order to group on it?

Comment: @PeterSmith although `FORMAT` does exist, is it a very slow performing function and best avoided.

Comment: The database is NOT the place to format stuff. Do this in the presentation layer.

Comment: I'm using Power Bi directquery so therefore I need to format this part in the SQL side

Comment: @KeithL Your code seemed to be closest to what I want however i got an arithmetic overflow error when I ran it.

Comment: @user11681655 it works on a date column. i see now on a answer below you are saying DateID isn't even a date. So that won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option is to use the implicit conversion.  In this case, `LEFT(DateID,7)`.

**Example Updated for INT**

```
Select DateID      = stuff(left(DateID,6),5,0,'-')
      ,[PayAmount] = sum([PayAmount])
      ,Customer
 From  YourTable
 Group By left(DateID,6),Customer
```

**Returns**

```
DateID   PayAmount      Customer
2019-03  300            A
2019-06  300            A
2019-04  200            B
2019-06  300            B
```

Comment: I tried you example but it returned DateId as just and int should I add  
    Convert(DATE,Convert(CHAR(8),DateId),112) into this query as well

Comment: @user11681655 Does DateID have a datatype of Date?

Comment: Yes In the presentation layer I need this column to already be converted to date format

Comment: @user11681655  I don't see how that would be possible unless DateID is not a date  Take a peek at https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=289d9a33f13ca4b78237d97f1fd33b49

Comment: Okay I see what your saying, DateId is an int originally in the (yyyymmdd) format. Is it possible for me to convert Dateid into a date type and then knock off the days and group by the months like the query you just posted? Thanks for the help

Comment: @user11681655 To answer your question,  You can convert an INT into a DATE  ,,, convert(Date,left(DateID,8))

Comment: This worked great, is there anyway I can keep this same output/query but have DateId be converted into a date value?

Comment: @user11681655 Not if you are stripping off the days.   Another option is to set each date to the 1st or even end of month.

Comment: @user11681655  Take a peek at https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=41f8b756549b2970be7c06d26fe2d739   DON'T be fooled by the format of the date

Answer (score 0):

This seems like you just need the first 7 characters of the ISO8601 style:

```
CONVERT(varchar(7),DateId,126)
```

If you want to retain the `date` datatype, then you'll need to "round" the date to the start of the month. One common way of doing this is the below method of getting the difference in months between the value and date "0" (`1900-01-01`):

```
CONVERT(date,DATEADD(MONTH,DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, DateId),0))
```

If you then need to show the format `yyyy-MM` you can set that as your format in your presentation layer.

If you need to group by that as well, then add that expression to your `GROUP BY` clause.